# mysql calculated field based on regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to update a field based on another field.

Data looks like this:

```
id|Measurement

1|15x52 9x2
```

Ultimately, I'd like the calculated field like:

```
id|Measurement|calcField

1|15x52 9x2|798
```

Measurement may have "Hello, George", etc. so only if we find a [digit]x[digit] we should calculate.

I would be happy with:

```
id|Measurement|calcField

1|15x52 9x2|780 18
```

Any assistance will be appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Why not figure this out in your application code and insert it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Mainly I'm looking for regex to match this pattern.  It seems the best place is where the data is.  I may want to do an update on the table in the future.  I had luck with this `IF(Address REGEXP '^[0-9]', SUBSTRING(Address, LOCATE(' ', Address)+1), Address) AS addrSort` which separates a street number from an address but I'm having trouble with **[digit]x[digit]** pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `LOCATE()` to find the space and `x` characters, get the substrings between them, and do the arithmetic with those substrings. Unfortunately, this is really verbose when there's no regexp matcher that can extract parts of the string.

```
IF(Measurement REGEXP '^[0-9]+x[0-9]+ [0-9]+x[0-9]+$',
   LEFT(Measurement, LOCATE('x', Measurement)-1) *
   SUBSTR(Measurement, LOCATE('x', Measurement)+1, LOCATE(' ', Measurement)-LOCATE('x', Measurement))
   +
   SUBSTR(Measurement, LOCATE(' ', Measurement)+1, LOCATE('x', Measurement, LOCATE(' ', Measurement))-LOCATE(' ', Measurement)-1) *
   SUBSTR(Measurement, LOCATE('x', Measurement, LOCATE(' ', Measurement))+1), 0)
```

if you have to handle an arbitrary number of `###x

Comment: Thank you for your response!  That query is taking a very long time to run - hasn't stopped yet.  Would this handle 3x3 45x4 dog 54x6 etc.?  There may be multiple occurrences and some text.

Comment: No, it won't work for that, it only handles `###x### ###x###`. It's really hard to do parsing in MySQL. If you have to handle more general strings, you should probably write a stored function that does it using loops.

Comment: But even finding the first numeric character is difficult in a stored procedure.

Comment: I appreciate your help - could you leave me with finding all occurrences of ##x## in a string and I'll figure out something to do?

Comment: There's no easy way to do that in MySQL -- there's no looping outside stored procedures.

Comment: In the procedure you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to find each space-delimited substring.

Comment: Ok, thank you - I thought there was a way to find all occurrences of a particular string like **##x##** **##x##** dog **##x##**.

Comment: Not in MySQL. But if you search for regular expression UDFs, you may find something you can use.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. Though not directly in MySQL, I am pulling from MySQL field.  I hope it helps someone.

```
$select_query = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$output_array = array();

$search = preg_match_all("/\b[0-9]+x[0-9]*\b/", $select_query->GridCardMeasurements, $output_array);
$sfTotal = 0;

foreach ($output_array[0] as $valuex) {
  $sf = explode("x", $valuex);
  $sfTotal += $sf[0]*$sf[1];
}
```